# I can't figure out why my data counting doesn't work right?

Tags: c#, counter

Ok, My counting does work somewhat, meaning that it display correct number when data is added and deleted.

The problem is that if I add only 1 entry, I am displayed that I have 1 entry, but if I delete the only entry there is, my counter is still showing 1. Why not 0?

This is how I do it (the fields where I am updating my panel titles are on the bottom):

```
    public void DisplayFileContent(string filePath)
    {
        lvPC.Items.Clear();
        lvWeb.Items.Clear();
        lvSerialCode.Items.Clear();

        string hashShortPass = hash.ShortHash(storedAuth.Password);
        // Counting all entries.
        int countEntries = 0;

        int countPC = 0;
        int countWeb = 0;
        int countSerial = 0;

        string connectionString =
            @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={0};
              Persist Security Info=False; Jet OLEDB:Database Password={1};";

        // Encrypting/Decrypting  data.
        Security security = new Security();

        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = string.Format(connectionString, filePath, hashShortPass);

            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
                ("Select * FROM PersonalData", connection))
            {
                try
                {
                    // Open database connection.
                    connection.Open();

                    using (OleDbDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        // Checking if there is any data in the file.
                        if (read.HasRows)
                        {
                            // Reading information from the file.
                            while (read.Read())
                            {
                                // Count all entries read from the reader.
                                countEntries++;

                                if (security.DecryptAES(read.GetString(1), 
                                    storedAuth.Password, storedAuth.UserName) 
                                        == "PC Password")
                                {
                                    // Count PC passwords.
                                    countPC++;
                                    PC.Tag = read.GetInt32(0);
                                    lvPC.Items.Add(PC);
                                }
                                else if (security.DecryptAES(read.GetString(1), 
                                    storedAuth.Password, storedAuth.UserName) 
                                        == "Web Site Password")
                                {
                                    countWeb++;
                                    Web.Tag = read.GetInt32(0);
                                    lvWeb.Items.Add(Web);
                                }
                                else if (security.DecryptAES(read.GetString(1), 
                                    storedAuth.Password, storedAuth.UserName) 
                                        == "Serial Code")
                                {
                                    countSerial++;
                                    Serial.Tag = read.GetInt32(0);
                                }

                                tabPage1.Text = "PC Passwords ( " + countPC + " )";
                                tabPage2.Text = "Web Site Passwords ( " + countWeb + " )";
                                tabPage3.Text = "Serial Codes ( " + countSerial + " )";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Set some breakpoints, debug and step through the code.

Comment: Checking read.HasRows is redundant because read.Read() will return false if there are no more rows to be read, but that can't be the issue here.  Can you confirm that, at the end of execution, `countPC + countWeb + countSerial == countEntries`?  Nothing is being caught by your exception handler?

Comment: @BACON: No, there is no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if you delete an entry, the code that updates the labels is not getting executed.

You need to move the following block:

```
tabPage1.Text = "PC Passwords ( " + countPC + " )";
tabPage2.Text = "Web Site Passwords ( " + countWeb + " )";
tabPage3.Text = "Serial Codes ( " + countSerial + " )";
```

after the `}` associated with this statement:

```
if (read.HasRows)
```

Also, since the HasRows is not needed, you can rewrite it something like:

```
using (OleDbDataReader read = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    // Reading information from the file.
    while (read.Read())
    {
        // Count all entries read from the reader.
        countEntries++;

        if (security.DecryptAES(read.GetString(1), 
            storedAuth.Password, storedAuth.UserName) 
                == "PC Password")
        {
            // Count PC passwords.
            countPC++;
            PC.Tag = read.GetInt32(0);
            lvPC.Items.Add(PC);
        }
        else if (security.DecryptAES(read.GetString(1), 
            storedAuth.Password, storedAuth.UserName) 
                == "Web Site Password")
        {
            countWeb++;
            Web.Tag = read.GetInt32(0);
            lvWeb.Items.Add(Web);
        }
        else if (security.DecryptAES(read.GetString(1), 
            storedAuth.Password, storedAuth.UserName) 
                == "Serial Code")
        {
            countSerial++;
            Serial.Tag = read.GetInt32(0);
        }
    }
}

tabPage1.Text = "PC Passwords ( " + countPC + " )";
tabPage2.Text = "Web Site Passwords ( " + countWeb + " )";
tabPage3.Text = "Serial Codes ( " + countSerial + " )";
```

Comment: I have tried that but moving outside of brackets doesn't bring right results. The Text statements are executed because they do update number of elements in database, the problem is that it won't count only if 1 entry is added, and when its deleted, it's still saying 1.

Comment: No! Wait, you are right. I was playing around and defined them as global, so they didn't reset each time entry was added. But when I made them local to this method, it works fine now. Thanks!